# (105: No buffer space available) while connecting to upstream,

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, linux-kernel, websocket

The server is returning 500 error.
And in the logs I see many records like 
(105: No buffer space available) while connecting to upstream

Tried to restart server : didn't help. 
Increased the number of sockets : didn't help.

VPS, running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit (with VestaCP if it is important) 
apache2 Nginx.

Memory:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           8192        1688        5237         330        1266        6277
Swap:             0           0           0
Total:         8192        1688        5237
```

Disk space is also sufficient:

```
Filesystem        1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop35701p1 423434036 228973348 173279660  57% /
devtmpfs            4194304         0   4194304   0% /dev
tmpfs               4194304         0   4194304   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               4194304      8412   4185892   1% /run
tmpfs                  5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs               4194304         0   4194304   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                4194304         0   4194304   0% /run/shm
```

inodes:

```
Filesystem          Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/ploop35701p1 52953088 933621 52019467    2% /
```

What can I do (desperated)?

Comment: did you trie to check the number of inodes using df -i ?

Comment: Filesystem                Inodes          IUsed      IFree I         Use%       
/dev/ploop35701p1   52953088     933621   52019467    2% /
so also low usage

Comment: Please show the content of `/proc/user_beancounters`.

Comment: i thought any question which has an control panels are out of scope?

Comment: Try to use the `strace -p <pid-of-daemon>` to trace the issue.

Comment: @Michael Hampton
/proc/user_beancounters
bash: /proc/user_beancounters: Permission denied
(Because it is VPS?)

Comment: @AntonDanilov 
What is daemon in this case? nginx?

Comment: Did you try `sudo`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton   Sorry, was looking wrong.
This is the only value with (high) failcnt. 
 numtcpsock                    678                  750                  750                  750               687614

Comment: Those limits are absurdly low. Complain to your provider, and consider not using OpenVZ VPSes in future.